# JMeter - How to make post processors reusable and use them on top of a test fragment on demand

Tags: jmeter

**Here is my scenario:**

I created a test fragment for a sampler which is being used in many thread groups present in different jmx scripts. I sometimes would like to extract few values of this sampler result using few post processors.

**Question:**

How do I group and make these post processors reusable? I do not want to include as part of the test fragment itself as I don't need/want to execute post processor action every time.

**Here is what I have tried:**

I am able to save those post processors as a separate test fragment and include it in my test script right after the test fragment with the sampler whenever I want to execute them. I can save the sampler result to a jmeter variable and use it inside my post processor test fragment.

Is this a good approach? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Having Post-Procesors at the same level as all other Samplers is not a very good idea as they will be executed for each Sampler in their [scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules)
- Saving response data into a variable each time is also an overhead as according to your question you need the value `sometimes`

I would recommend using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to copy previous sampler response data and apply necessary Post-Processor(s) to it as child(ren).

The relevant code to copy the previous sampler response data would be as simple as:

```
SampleResult.setResponseData(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData())
```

Where:

- `SampleResult` - stands for current [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
- `ctx` - stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter conctept

The JSR223 Sampler can be saved as a Test Fragment as well.

Comment: As suggested, I added JSR223 Sampler as a test fragment with post processors to it and calling this in my script whenever I needed to extract values. It worked flawless. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Dmitri T answer, in [JSR PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) you can save similar code in script file and reuse it

> Script file A file containing the script to run, if a relative file path is used, then it will be relative to directory referenced by "user.dir" System property

Use the same script file in several post processors for re-usability:
[image]